# Animate Auto Layout backed view using UIKitDynamics

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, uikit-dynamics

I'd like to use a UIKitDynamics **UISnapBehaviour** to spice up the animation (appearance + position change on rotation) of a button that itself is positioned in a view using Auto Layout.

I understand that while applying UIKitDynamics forces I need to disable auto-layout constraints from the button temporarily. I am thinking of the following process …

1. Get the **target center/bounds** of the button **before the Auto Layout based transition** happens (but after it is triggered). Save that value.
2. Temporarily **disable** all Auto Layout/constraints of the button
3. Apply the UISnapBehaviour. Feed it with the saved target center or bounds value from Auto Layout (from step 1).
4. When the UIKitDynamics animation is finished **re-enable** the constraints to prepare for any further layout change

Is this the right approach?

Which delegate/layout should be used for those those respective steps + how do I get the **target center** of a view from Auto Layout **before** the actual Auto Layout based animation/transition happens?

Comment: You don't actually need to disable constraints on a view in order to use UIKitDynamics with auto-layout. There is a neat trick someone showed me a while ago, that if you create a custom NSObject than conforms to <UIDynamicItem>, add a behavior to this custom item  and then change the constraints in the action block of the behavior.

Comment: This is the correct answer, animate the constraints, not the frame.

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest a different approach that approximates the `UISnapBehavior`, but avoids trying to marry UIKit Dynamics with an auto layout where you are relying upon the auto layout engine to determine the final position of the view. (Obviously, if you knew the final destination, then you'd just suspend auto layout, snap, and when the snap was done, you'd then apply the constraints.)

For the bouncing effect as the view snaps into place, you can use `animateWithDuration` with `usingSpringWithDamping` parameter, e.g.:

```
// create the view

UIView *view = ...;
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:view];

// add all of the constraints for the final position

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);
[self.view addConstraints:...];

// animate the application of those constraints with low `withSpringWithDamping`

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

If you also want some rotation as it snaps into place, you can use `animateKeyframesWithDuration`:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4 / 2);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_4 / 4);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.75 relativeDuration:0.125 animations:^{
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4 / 16);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.875 relativeDuration:0.125 animations:^{
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

This isn't precisely the `UISnapBehavior`, but approximates it pretty closely. You can play around with the timing and amount of rotations in the key frame animation as well as the spring damping factor, too. But this illustrates one approach to get snap-like behavior using block-based animation.